# Proper method for implementing API on an ARM based firmware

Tags: api, arm

I am developing a device firmware based on an LPC17XX+FreeRTOS. My development environment is Eclipse + GCC, codes are in C. The requirement of the end product is:

1. A "base firmware" running RTOS and performing some periodic task (eg. perform health check).
2. The base firmware needs to support an API which will have some functions for data manipulation/delay/timing and some functions for using the device ports and I/O.
3. The user can build their own app using this API.
4. The user app needs to reside in an empty space of the flash. (It will be sent to the device via Serial port and I plan to use IAP to save it on flash)
5. I want to start the app as a new task from the "base firmware".

Step 1 and 3 are fairly easy to implement. I am not sure what is the best way to implement 2,3 and 4. So far I've looked at Dynamic linking, jump tables, overlays etc and I am kind of lost. Can someone give me an overview of proper implementation steps?

Some related questions:

1. Any other way to develop firmware for a product which provide API based App/module development and loading?
2. What do I need to provide to the user for using the API? Will my API source code be open?

I am open to any ideas, thanks :)